# What is the proper way to trigger an action after value assignment in Python?

Tags: python, types

I want to create an int type with boundaries like:

`> a = BoundInt(2,4)`

`a` will only hold values 2, 3 or 4 and raise an error if a different value is assigned to it.

But since Python doesn't let me override assignment and using setters is no Pythonic I'm kind of lost.

How could I work this out in my class and what specific syntax would this require when assigning new values to my vars?

Comment: your best bet is probably to write an object with a `set` method that checks for validity. setters aren't Pythonic, no - but when all else fails there isn't really a better option. also, properties and decorators are encouraged syntax in this kind of situation

Comment: A bit unclear. You can't "override" assignment, because it won't modify your object, it will just rebind `a` to another object. You can even do `a = "string"`. Doesn't matter what was `a`'s type before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to attach this as an attribute to a class

You can do this via a property:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        if not (2 <= value <= 4):
            raise ValueError
        self._a = value
```

Note that I *am* using a setter.  Python style generally discourages using a function when attribute access will do.  However, if you *need* to take some action when you set a variable, then a traditional setter or property is fine (depending on the API you want to expose).

If you actually want to do this using a syntax similar to what you've already written, maybe using a descriptor:

```
class BoundInt(object):
  def __init__(self, lower, upper, name):
      self.lower = lower
      self.upper = upper
      self.name = '_' + name

  def __get__(self, inst, cls):
      return getattr(inst, self.name)

  def __set__(self, inst, val):
      if self.lower <= val <= self.upper:
          setattr(inst, self.name, val)
      else:
          raise ValueError('must be in bounds!')

class Foo(object):
    a = BoundInt(2, 4, 'a')

f = Foo()
f.a = 2
print(f.a)
f.a = 3
print(f.a)
f.a = 4
print(f.a)
f.a = 5
```

results in:

```
2
3
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/home/mgilson/sandbox/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    f.a = 5
  File "/usr/home/mgilson/sandbox/test.py", line 15, in __set__
    raise ValueError('must be in bounds!')
ValueError: must be in bounds!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property:

```
class BoundInt(object):

    def __init__(self, bottom, top):
       self.bounds = range(bottom, top)   # xrange for Python 2.x
       self._value = bottom

     @property
     def value():
         return self._value

     @value.setter
     def value(x):
          if x in self.bounds:
             self._value = x
          else:
              raise ValueError("%s is not in %r" % (x, self.bounds))
```

Problem here is that you have to hold your value as an attribute of your object, and then implement all the methods of `int` that allow you to use it as a number.  In Python, this is basically unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `int`:

```
class BoundInt(int):
    def __init__(self, x, allowed=(2, 3, 4), *args, **kwargs):
        value = int(x, *args, **kwargs)
        if value not in allowed:
            raise ValueError("Not in allowed values: " + repr(allowed))
        else:
            self = value

a = BoundInt(2)
print a + 3
b = BoundInt('11', base=2)
print b - a
c = BoundInt(7)
```

Please note, that you cannot prevent in Python `assigment` or value to name. Operator `=` only binds existing object (value of right hand expression) to a variable name. In Python it is value, that has type, not variable name.

Comment: to use a syntax like this I should write a class factory or something that returns BoundInt, right? like 
`bIntClass = BoundIntFactory(min=2, max=4);
val = bIntClass(3)`

Comment: Note that writing `self = int(value)` does nothing here.  The integer is already created -- it's value set until reaped by the garbage collector.  Yours works because it raises the exception in `__init__` after the integer is created, but before it can be assigned to anything.

Comment: @mgilson indeed, that was my quirky way to write invariant ;) I edited it out and added support for different bases.

Comment: @dnuske you can write a decorator that validates arguments (maybe better to pass validation as function in this case). And in Python 3.4+ you can use [annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations) to pack validation right into signature (you can later verify with decorator or inside the function).